# Firebase getToken() TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the token of my currently signed in user of my website. However, javascript cannot get the value for me. I think there are 2 problems here:

1. When I'm getting Auth.currentUser at start, I get this error of "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of null". But when I type Auth.currentUser.getToken() in the console, the object with the token actually shows up.
2. What getToken() returns to me is a promise object with its key 'ea' containing the value of the token. but when I do Auth.currentUser.getToken().ea it gets me 'null'. How can I retrieve the token directly from the object?

Thanks!

My code of retrieving the token:

```
var Auth = firebase.auth()
var token = Auth.currentUser.getToken()
```

This screenshot might be helpful:
[image: Chrome console result]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `firebase.User:getIdToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken):

> Returns a JWT token used to identify the user to a Firebase service.
>
> Returns the current token if it has not expired, otherwise this will refresh the token and return a new one.

The method returns a promise, since it may require a round-trip to the Firebase servers in case the token has expired:

```
Auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(data => console.log(data))
```

Or in more classic JavaScript:

```
Auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Log output:

> ey...biPA

**Update**: to ensure that the user is signed in before getting the token, run the above code in an [`onAuthStateChanged` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Although this way do directly gets me the token string, it still doesn't solve the issue of the TypeError. But really appreciated for your answer, it helps.

Comment: That means there is no current user, i.e. you didn't sign in yet.

Comment: Does this mean if there are, say, 20 ajax calls I am making each of which call different API endpoint, all those 20 functions have to enclose the ajax requests within the auth.onStateChangedListener() ? Wouldn't that make my code redundant?

Comment: Hi, I am using the same code from your updated answer and I get a user object. Inside the if (user) block I console.log the user object or user.uid and prints out the user or user id but user.getIdToken() throw an error: "user.getIdToken is not a function". I am not able to get the user token id. Maybe you can help. Thanks!

Comment: I was using firebase 3.6.9. Updating to 4.9.1 solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample on how to get the id token using NodeJS

```
var firebase = require('firebase')
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey:*********
    databaseURL:*********
})

var customToken = *********    
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).catch(function(error) {
    var errorMessage = error.message
    console.log(errorMessage)
})

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken().then(data => console.log(data))
    } else {
        console.log('onAuthStateChanged else')
    }
})
```