# Firebase auth TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null

Tags: firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get the user token using

```
import { auth, database } from "firebase";

await token = await auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
```

but instead, I am getting this error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null
```

Its sometimes work but sometimes it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934898/firebase-gettoken-typeerror-cannot-read-property

Comment: @NovoLucas that didn't help me, I am getting user as null.

Answer (score 2):

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
         if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
           console.log(data)
          });
         }
        });
```

Comment: What if you need the token and the auth state hasn't changed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's best idea according to security issues but I found it helpful:

```
let currentUser;
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    currentUser = user;
  } else {
  }
})
```