# How to get credential.accessToken at Firebase currentUser ? (Firebase Google Sign In)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, token, access-token, credentials

I'm using firebase Sign in Google to sign my users (React web app)
I'm setting a provider to also access user google drive info:

```
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly');
let { user, additionalUserInfo, credential } = await firebase.auth()
                                                      .signInWithPopup(provider);
```

That way I can get the `credential.accessToken` to make requests to G Drive API

But when I need to get currentUser with:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
```

I can't find `credential.accessToken` at `user` object.

There is any way to access that ?

Or I need to store a new cookie with that token when user first sign in ?

I have tried:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    user.getIdToken().then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
});
```

from: [Firebase getToken() TypeError: Cannot read property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934898/firebase-gettoken-typeerror-cannot-read-property)

But that function only returns the `accessToken` to login an user, it does have the same name but it's a different token.